# How to retrieve ProcessWorkflowHistory

Tags: core-service

I am trying to automate Workflow. Below code start the workflow and everything goes fine and I get current processinstanceid

```
 ProcessInstanceData pid =  _CoreServiceClient.StartWorkflow(publicationURI, instruction, _ReadOptions);
```

However the pid object is not found when the workflow completed and Read method gives exception

```
 IdentifiableObjectData processInstanceObj = _CoreServiceClient.Read(pid.Id, _ReadOptions);
```

Is there anyway to get processhistoryinstance id of the processinstancedata (without any hardcoding in code/config file)?

Answer (score 1):

When a workflow finishes, the Process Instance is deleted and a Process History is created.
The ProcessInstance.Finish method returns the ProcessHistory.
You could pick up the Process History ID in a ProcessInstance Finish event handler.

Comment: ProcessInstanceData  is not showing any Finish Property/method. Could you please elaborate the details bit more.