# How to find if all the activities of a workflow has completed using core service

Tags: core-service, workflow

Is there any way to confirm if a workflow started using core service api from my console application is completed or still any activity left? I am unable to find it because :
1. procesinstancedata become processhistorydata. Hence the processinstancedata tcm id which I had when I started the workflow become invalid and read operation throw error.
2. Number of activities are different for different workflows hence can not go for loop in activities.
3. I am using StartWorkFlowAsync method so that I can start workflow in asynchronously however I don't see any event in core api to subscribe for completion of workflow event i.e. when process instance become process history.

Answer (score 1):

As you start workflow yourself and you have control over the `StartWorkflowInstructionData` you can set `ProcessInstanceTitle` or `ActivityTitle` properties to unique values. You can then get list of process histories and see if the process history with this title and / or first activity title is present.

Alternatively you could create event handler which will be triggered on ProcessHistory create.

Comment: For one of similar question http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12586/how-to-retrieve-processworkflowhistory  I received that response. Could you please confirm in case you have come across properties mentioned there.

Comment: What is written there is going to work in TOM.NET, there're no ready to use events in CoreService